# 'env: ruby_noexec_wrapper: No such file or directory' error in PhpStorm SASS compilation on Mac

Tags: macos, compiler-construction, path, sass, phpstorm

I read around a lot and tried different things but my *PhpStorm* just doesn't want to compile my SASS/SCSS files into CSS files.

Here are pictures of my **File Watcher configuration** and the **error message** it causes:

[image: My File Watcher configuration.]

[image: The error when the File Watcher runs (after saving changes).]

I also tried doing it over **External Tools**, but although I tried two different approaches, both lead to the same error. The **two configurations** and the **error** can be seen in the following pictures:

[image: My first approach over External Tools.]

[image: My second approach over External Tools.]

[image: The error caused by both approaches stating 'env: ruby_noexec_wrapper: No such file or directory'.]

Does anyone know what I have to do to **get it work**?

Comment: Does `sass` command work from the Terminal? If so, try running PhpStorm from the Terminal so that it inherits the same environment: `open -a /Applications/PhpStorm.app/`. If it helps, [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/135688/104891) for more details how to make it work when PhpStorm is started normally.

Comment: Thanks a lot, doing step by step what you said helped me solving this problem. Wanna post this as answer so I can mark it as the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac it may be required to perform additional steps outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135688/104891) to make the environment the same as in Terminal for the GUI applications.

Most likely `PATH` is different.

Another workaround is to start PhpStorm from the Terminal:

`open -a /Applications/PhpStorm.app/`